# Spring mvc maven - adding libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating a spring mvc application. I am came across maven recently and planning to use it with my current project.

I have downloaded maven and configured it on my machine and using the command line interface.

I created a project with following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.priyank -DartifactId=SpringWebApp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

After that I updated my pom.xml file with dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.priyank</groupId>
 <artifactId>SpringWebApp</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <name>SpringWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring dependencies -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- hibernate dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
   <finalName>SpringWebApp</finalName>
 </build>
</project>
```

After updating pom.xml from my command line I executed:

```
mvn install
```

which downloaded all dependencies in my local repo.

After that I converted it to my eclipse project using command:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

Now after importing this project SpringWebApp in my workspace I can see libraries included in manner like this:

[image: Eclipse Prjoect Navigator]

Usually when I create Spring mvc without maven, I put my libraries under WEB-INF\lib folder.

I am confused here. Seems I have done something wrong. What is the right way to include this libraries in project?

P.S.: This added jre 1.4 as my runtime, but I have changed it to 1.7

Comment: I strongly suggest a read on what maven is and how it helps you. Maven places the libraries in that exact spot when you create a war file with it.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thank you for the suggestion. Can your recommend me a tutorial. I am a very beginner to maven, I am planning to use it for my team. Need guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer use m2e plugin include in eclipse to make .classpath / .project and .settings of eclipse configuration then eclipse:eclipse goal.

When you configure eclipse project with m2e plugin classpath libraries is done like this:
[image]

And all dependencies are deploy in WEB-INF/lib automatically by eclipse and into war by maven-war-plugin.

to force use of specific version of java you need to specify version in configuration of maven-compiler-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```